# Google app engine quota is expired, how to provision new instances on emergency basis

Tags: google-app-engine, provisioning, billing

My app engine is running in free quote. Today quota usage is exceeded (28 hours per day). All client requests are rejected with "Over quota" exception.

I enabled billing in my admin console (Settings -> Project billing status -> enable billing). I have valid credit card in billing settings, but still instances are not provisioned and client requests are rejected with same error.

What should I do to get the instances provisioned immediately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Contacted google support and they mentioned that in addition to enabling billing, I need to set daily quota for my app engine.

In admin console on left side panel, under Compute -> AppEngine -> settings -> edit application settings and set daily budget.

I could see instances provisioned after this setting and client requests are getting processed.